# Angular: MatSort not working when using object inside datasource

Tags: angular, angular-material

I have an angular 6 application which has a Mat Table. Data for the table is populated like below. Sorting works for the fields `position` and `name`, but not `weight` and `symbol` which are part of the `detail` object. I have also tried naming the columns like `detail.weight` in `displayedColumns` and `matColumnDef` but with no luck. Please advise what am I doing wrong ?

```
const ELEMENT_DATA: PeriodicElement[] = [
  {position: 1, name: 'Hydrogen', detail: {weight: 4.0026, symbol: 'He'}},
  {position: 2, name: 'Helium', detail: {weight: 4.0026, symbol: 'He'}},
]

displayedColumns: string[] = ['position', 'name', 'weight', 'symbol'];
```

Template

```
 <ng-container matColumnDef="weight">
    <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header> Weight </th>
    <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.detail.weight}} </td>
  </ng-container>
```

Here is the stackblitz url for the issue
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-kumdeq

Comment: I faced the same problems as you (and some more missing features for angular material table).

Because of that I created some library which does also provide out of the box sorting by subproperties of an object.

have a look at this lib https://github.com/mikelgo/ngx-mat-table-extensions/tree/master/libs/ngx-mat-table.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use sortingDataAccessor, which

> Allows for sort customization by overriding sortingDataAccessor, which
>   defines how data properties are accessed.

Add this code snippet inside ngOnInit:

```
   this.dataSource.sortingDataAccessor = (item, property) => {
     switch (property) {
       case 'weight': return  item.detail.weight;
       case 'symbol': return  item.detail.symbol;
       default: return item[property];
  }
```

Link: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-kumdeq-z4bags

Comment: Tnx for help SIR.